# How to get all child pages and sub-child of a that page by the parent page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

`Parent
- Child
-- Sub Child
--- Sub Sub Child`

I want to get all child pages and sub-child of a that page by the parent page in WordPress.
I want this in `$wpdb->get_results` so i can add classes and ids

Comment: I want all sub sub pages

Comment: yes but that function just show child page not sub child pages

Comment: I got the answer can u please help me to post all code of php here

Comment: I am sorry for wrong comment please use this function [get_pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) and pass parent page id in `child_of` parameter.

Comment: I complete already but unable to post solution here

Comment: Just post it as an answer :)

Comment: I try but it is very different in output of answer